# Video-JS issue playing on iPad (sound only)

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, video.js

I have a website that has a video playing on it using Video-JS. It works fine, apart from on an iPad, in which case there is a 50/50 chance that the video will play with audio only. However, rotating the iPad causes the video to display properly, at the point that it should be at (synced with the audio).

I am not entirely sure what's going wrong, since sometimes it does work so I doubt it is the video stream itself. Apart from that the video-js integration script is pretty textbook and seems to work on everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around which is by simply clearing the cache :)